# Make a test depend on a file() or make_directory() call

Tags: cmake, ctest

I have a test (`add_test(NAME MyTest COMMAND MyExecutable`) that I would like to run only have some "preparation" tasks have been done. When I have one test that depends on another test, I will use `SET_TESTS_PROPERTIES(TestA PROPERTIES DEPENDS AnotherTest)`, but is there a way I can do something like `SET_TESTS_PROPERTIES(TestA PROPERTIES DEPENDS file(REMOVE /path/to/file))`?

Answer (score 0):

The one way I can think of  is using some Python or other scripts as test driver in following way as per [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/command/add_test.html#command:add_test):

```
add_test(NAME test_req_some_ops_before
        COMMAND testDriver.py --config $<CONFIGURATION>
                              --exe $<TARGET_FILE:myexe>
                              --path <here path to delete>)
```

which should do whatever you want

Comment: I see what you mean. We don't actually need the `--config` and `--exe` here, right? Just `add_test(NAME test_req_some_ops_before
        COMMAND DeletePath.py --path-to-delete <here path to delete>)` would work, right?

Comment: If you don't need generic script - yes.  ```--config``` and ```--exe``` will be used if you'll make some generic test runner.